# if the repetend length of $b\over a$ being larger or equal than $m-1$ then $m$ is prime?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, totient-function

> If :  $a,b\in\Bbb{N}$
>
> and we have :
>
> $$a=2^\alpha. 5^\beta.m$$
>
> $$\forall m  : (m,10)=1$$

Now how we can show **if the period (repetend length) of $b\over a$ being larger or equal than $m-1$ then $m$ is prime?**

**Example** : $a=70$ , $b=3$
$$a=2^1\times5^1\times7$$ $$(7,10)=1$$

$${b\over a}={3\over 70}=0.0\overline{428571}\Rightarrow repetend \, length =6$$ 
$$6\ge m-1= 7-1 $$
$$\Rightarrow 7 \,is \, \underline{ prime}  $$

I'm trying to use Euler's totient function for m and proving that we can divide it by repetend length of $b\over a$ and use this for main question, but i couldn't prove it too.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds promising. What has Euler's totient function to do with the length of the period? If you can answer that, you're a good piece of the way in.

Comment: @DanielFischer i just know that the period of 1/k always divides Euler's phi function of k

Comment: Have you any idea why?

Comment: It has to do with the order of $10$ modulo $m$. If $r$ is the smallest positive integer such that $10^r \equiv 1 \pmod{m}$, then $1/m$ has period $r$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks you are right . and after that we have r|$\phi (m) $ and we can replace m-1 with r and prove m is prime . I'm sorry but i can't show it for ${b\over a}$
Please help me how should i do ,Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sufficient (if true) but not necessary:  $$\dfrac{3}{130}=0.023\overline{076923}$$

Comment: @Piquito Yes, it's true. The period length is always (if $\gcd(a,b) = 1$) the muliplicative order of $10$ modulo $m$, so a divisor of $\varphi(m)$. If the period length is $m-1$, it follows that $\varphi(m) = m-1$, i.e. $m$ is prime. [But of course the converse is far from true, lots of primes have shorter period.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we note that factors of $2$ or $5$ in the denominator don't influence the period length.

If $r,s \in \mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}$ are coprime with $r < s$, and the decimal expansion of $\frac{r}{s}$ has a preperiod of length $\gamma$ and a period of length $\ell$, we have

\begin{align}
\frac{r}{s} &= \sum_{k = 1}^{\gamma} \frac{c_k}{10^k} + \sum_{m = 0}^{\infty}\sum_{r = 1}^{\ell} \frac{d_r}{10^{\gamma + r + m\ell}} \\
&= 10^{-\gamma}\underbrace{\sum_{k = 1}^{\gamma} 10^{\gamma-k}c_k}_C + 10^{-\gamma}\underbrace{\sum_{r = 1}^{\ell} 10^{\ell-r}d_r}_D \sum_{m = 0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{10^{(m+1)\ell}} \\
&= \frac{C}{10^{\gamma}} + \frac{D}{10^{\gamma}\bigl(10^{\ell}-1\bigr)} \\
&= \frac{\bigl(10^{\ell}-1\bigr)C + D}{10^{\gamma}\bigl(10^{\ell}-1\bigr)},
\end{align}

so $s \mid 10^{\gamma}\bigl(10^{\ell}-1\bigr)$. Writing $s = 2^{\alpha}\cdot 5^{\beta}\cdot m$ with $\gcd(10,m) = 1$, it follows that $\max \{\alpha,\beta\} \leqslant \gamma$, and $m \mid 10^{\ell}-1$.

Conversely, if $s = 2^{\alpha}\cdot 5^{\beta}\cdot m$ with $\gcd(10,m) = 1$ and $m > 1$, let $\gamma = \max \{\alpha,\beta\}$ and $\ell$ the multiplicative order of $10$ modulo $m$, i.e. $\ell = \min \{ k \in \mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\} : 10^k \equiv 1 \pmod{m}\}$. Then for $u = \frac{10^{\ell}-1}{m}$ we have

$$\frac{r}{s} = \frac{2^{\gamma - \alpha}\cdot 5^{\gamma - \beta}\cdot u\cdot r}{10^{\gamma}\bigl(10^{\ell}-1\bigr)}$$

and with $2^{\gamma - \alpha}\cdot 5^{\gamma - \beta}\cdot u\cdot r = \bigl(10^{\ell}-1\bigr)\cdot C + D$, where $0 < D < 10^{\ell}-1$, we get a decimal expansion with preperiod of length (at most<sup>(1)</sup>) $\gamma$ and period of length $\ell$ reversing the computation above.

So we see that the period length of the decimal expansion is independent of the exponents of $2$ and $5$ in the prime factorisation of the denominator. As long as the numerator and the denominator are coprime, the period length is also independent of the numerator. We summarise:

> If $a,b \in \mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\}$ are coprime with $a = 2^{\alpha}\cdot 5^{\beta}\cdot m$ with $\gcd(10,m) = 1$ and $m > 1$, then the (minimal) period length of the decimal expansion of $\frac{b}{a}$ is $$\ell := \min \{ k \in \mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\} : 10^k \equiv 1 \pmod{m}\}.$$

We have $\ell \mid \varphi(m)$ since the order of $(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ is $\varphi(m)$. In particular, $\ell \leqslant \varphi(m)$. Since $\varphi(m) \leqslant m-1$ for $m > 1$, the period length can never be greater than $m-1$. Now if $\ell = m-1$, then $\varphi(m) = m-1$, and that means $m$ is prime. (For a composite number $n$ with prime factor $p$, we have $\varphi(n) \leqslant n-2$, since $n$ and $p$ are two different numbers in $\{1,2,\dotsc,n\}$ which aren't coprime to $n$.)

Note that the converse doesn't hold, there are lots of primes $p$ for which the period length is smaller than $p-1$.

<sup>(1)</sup> It is possible that some of the ending digits of $C$ coincide with those of $D$, in which case one could say that the periodic part starts at or before the $\gamma^{\text{th}}$ digit after the decimal point.

Comment: I appreciate your help ,but i'm so sorry that I can't completely understand your solution. I will work on it and hopefully i'll get it later .Thanks :)